# frame buffer 320x480 scaling images/2 = frame buffer 640x960 not scaling images?

Tags: objective-c, retina-display

i have readed many topic but i'm pretty confused.
it seems that:

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)] == YES && [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.00) {
     // RETINA DISPLAY
     self.contentScaleFactor = 2.0;
  }
```

my app prepare a framebuffer of size 320x480 without that checking above...and display it at whole screen.
i thought that if i load a 2x image and display it on the screen (scaled down/2) i have the same thing as prepare a framebuffer of 640x960 and not scaling down my sprite.
is it correct?
i hope so...otherwise i'll have to rewrite many of code! 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have finally bought a retina display device and the answer is NO.
contentScaleFactor = 2.0; for a retina display is not the same as
contentScaleFactor = 1.0; and loading double sized images and display scaled *0.5